# How to get posted blog text through BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, telegram-bot, blogger, pyrogram

I made a Telegram bot and use a plugin to get text of blog(blogger). But I'm getting following error.

**Code:**

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pyrogram import Client, filters, enums

@Client.on_message(filters.command("mzl"))
async def mzlyc(client, message):
    await client.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, action=enums.ChatAction.TYPING)
    mzr = message.text.split(None, 1)[1]
    mizoly = mzr.replace(" ", "+") if len(message.command) > 2 else mzr
    mizl = f"https://www.mizolyric.com/search?q={mizoly}&m=1"
    zol = requests.get(mizl).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(zol, 'html.parser')
    item = soup.select_one("div[id^='post-body-']").text
    if not item:
        return await client.send_message(message.chat.id, \
            text="I lyrics duh hi ka zawng hmu zo lo.",  \
            reply_to_message_id=message.id)
    itms = item.replace("Continue Reading", " ") if "Continue Reading" in item else item
    await client.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f"{itms}", reply_to_message_id=message.id)
```

This code works fine with this template: https://www.templatemark.com/2017/10/news16-magazine-blogger-template.html; but does not work with template https://www.templatemark.com/2020/05/msd-responsive-grid-style-blogger-template.html.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-08-21T19:21:40.630002+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker
2022-08-21T19:21:40.630002+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
2022-08-21T19:21:40.630002+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/plugins/Tools4/mzlyrics.py", line 17, in mzlyc
2022-08-21T19:21:40.630003+00:00 app[worker.1]:     item = soup.select_one("div[id^='post-body-']").text
2022-08-21T19:21:40.630003+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: this is probably happening when the search returnes no results, then your `item = soup.select_one("div[id^='post-body-']")` selection cant find any and returns None. 

so you can do a check on item before trying to get the text.

Comment: before you use `.text` you should first get item and check if it is not `None`. Different pages may have different structure or different IDs. OR you should display what you get in HTML. Server may detect that you use script and it may send warning or Captcha

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes:

```
zol = requests.get(mizl).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(zol.decode('utf-8','ignore'), 'html.parser')
```

Here's the issue with [encoding unicode characters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous) explained here.